# How to change the font size on a section with titlesec in latex preamble?

Tags: lyx, fontsize, sections-paragraphs

I'm using LyX version 2.1.5

I want to change the font size such as:

1. Chapter 14pt, bold, align center
2. Section 12pt, bold

LaTeX Preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{14pt}
```

for section what to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following. You may have to fune-tune it for your requirements.

```
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{14}\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.5em}{}
```

For the chapter you could replace `\Large` with an exact size specification. And there was a final parameter missing.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{16}\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{14pt}{}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `\fontsize{12}{14}` be followed by `\selectfont`?

Comment: That's what I also thought initially. But it does work without. And I have seen examples in The LaTeX Companion where they use `\fontsize` without `\selectfont`. I can't find the definite information about it. But it certainly wouldn't harm to add it.

Comment: Well, it's good to know code in `\titleformat` can be made lighter.

Comment: I have done some experimentation, and it seems `\bfseries` does the `\selectfont`. But it would probably be more robust to include it anyway.

Comment: I checked the definition, and indeed, `\bfseries`, and all similar commands, include a `\selectfont`.

Comment: That indeed explains everything… Thanks for the information!

Comment: thanks for the answer, it is true that \bfseries do \selectfont has been a running successfully. Wow